# Can't align div boxes to the center

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i'm developing this website : [www.sfitnesscenter.com](http://www.sfitnesscenter.com)

i'm trying to make the 4 boxes below the slider to be horizontally aligned 2 by 2 to the center. i've tried using margin:auto, but nothing changed.

here's the html

```
<section id="wrapsecond">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="services-wrap">
      <?php if( get_theme_mod('shortinfo_sb') ) { ?>
        <?php echo get_theme_mod('shortinfo_sb'); ?>
      <?php } else { ?>                      
        <?php echo '<h2>What We Do</h2>
        <p>We are passionate about our clients results.</p>'; } ?>
        <div class="space50"></div>

<!-- Home Boxes Section -->
      <div class="home_boxes">
      <?php
        for($bx=1; $bx<5; $bx++) { 
          if( get_theme_mod('page-setting'.$bx)) { 
            $bxquery = new WP_query('page_id='.get_theme_mod('page-setting'.$bx,true)); 
         while( $bxquery->have_posts() ) : $bxquery->the_post(); 
                        ?>
         <div class="one_third <?php if($bx%4==0){ ?>last_column<?php } ?>">
           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
           <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4><?php echo fitnesslite_content(22); ?>
           <span class="ReadMore"><?php _e('Read More','fitness-lite');?>   </span>
           </a>
         </div>
         <?php endwhile; }else{?>

          <div class="one_third <?php if($bx%4==0){ ?>last_column<?php } ?>">
          <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/thumb_0<?php echo $bx; ?>.jpg"><h4><?php _e('Page Title','fitness-lite'); ?><?php echo $bx; ?></h4><p><?php _e('Phasellus viverra aliquet magna quis interduming. Sed quis fringilla massa. In ut porttitor felis necing iaculis mi. Proin tempo...','fitness-lite');?></p><span class="ReadMore"><?php _e('Read More','fitness-lite');?></span>
</a></div>                        

          <?php }}?>
        </div>
        <!-- Home Boxes Section -->
      </div><!-- services-wrap-->
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div><!-- container -->
</section><div class="clear"></div>
```

and here's the css

```
/* = Services section css
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
#wrapsecond{ background-color:#272727; color:#fff; padding-bottom:100px; }
.services-wrap, #FrontBlogPost .BlogPosts{ visibility:hidden;}

.one_third{ margin:0 5% 3.5% 0; float:left; padding:25px; border:2px solid #fff;}
.one_third:hover{ border-color:#ff4e1c;}
.one_third:hover .ReadMore{ background-color:#ff4e1c;}

.one_third img{ width:100%;}
.one_third h4{font:600 18px/22px 'Roboto',sans-serif;  padding:20px 0; margin:0; text-transform:uppercase; color:#fff;}
.one_third h4 span{ color:#ff4e1c; font-weight:300;}

.one_third h4 span::after{content:" ________"; display:inline-block;}


.one_third p{ margin-bottom:20px; color:#fff;}
.last_column{clear:right; margin-right:0 !important; }

@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .one_third { min-width: 45% }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .one_third { max-width: 40% }
}

#wrapsecond h2{ font-size:40px; color:#fff; font-weight:600; margin-bottom:0; text-transform:uppercase; }
#wrapsecond h2 span{ color:#ff4e1c; font-weight:300; }
```

NB : 
actually, the layout should be like this
top left : aerobic class, 
top right : bellydance class,
bottom left : yoga class,
bottom right : zumba class

it was horizontally and vertically paralled, until my client put the contents the other day. nothing's change even after the photos was removed. so, i don't think it was caused by the dimension of those photos

Comment: The aspect ratio of the "bellydance class" source photo is different from the others. Correcting that might be an immediate way to solve this issue.

Comment: hmm... yeah, when i changed that one with the same photo as "aerobic class", it was back to normal. so, what should i do to automatically do that @NateWhittaker in Wordpress? do i have to install some kind of plugin?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised, but I don't know of an applicable Wordpress plugin off the top of my head. Being PHP, you might be able to roll your own with PHP's image functions (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php), though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `display` of the boxes to `inline-block` and reduce the `margin` a bit. And remove the `float` .
Change the `.one_third` class to the following

```
.one_third {
    margin: 0 3% 3.5% 0;
    padding: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

Avoid using floats . its a messy thing to deal with.

Comment: i have put the code to the CSS editor, but nothing change :(

Comment: @fady.noor you need to remove the current .one_third class and add the above code..